# Java: Format number in millions

Tags: java, formatting, numeric, numericupdown

Is there a way to use DecimalFormat (or some other standard formatter) to format numbers like this:

> 1,000,000     => 1.00M
>
> 1,234,567     => 1.23M
>
> 1,234,567,890 => 1234.57M

Basically dividing some number by 1 million, keeping 2 decimal places, and slapping an 'M' on the end.  I've thought about creating a new subclass of NumberFormat but it looks trickier than I imagined.

I'm writing an API that has a format method that looks like this:

```
public String format(double value, Unit unit); // Unit is an enum
```

Internally, I'm mapping Unit objects to NumberFormatters.  The implementation is something like this:

```
public String format(double value, Unit unit)
{
    NumberFormatter formatter = formatters.get(unit);
    return formatter.format(value);
}
```

Note that because of this, I can't expect the client to divide by 1 million, and I can't just use String.format() without wrapping it in a NumberFormatter.

Comment: Do you want to handle M(ega) only, or also (G)iga, (T)era, etc?

Comment: It actually represents a security's volume, so it's M(illions) and potentially B(illions) but I'll be happy with just the M.

Comment: [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4753251/983430) has been getting much attention recently (due to a bounty).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
String.format("%.2fM", theNumber/ 1000000.0);
```

For more information see the [String.format javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: Just in case: use 1000000.0 instead.

Comment: Minor nitpick, looks like his code is using longs or ints so you can dispense with the floating point arithmetic:

Comment: If I leave off the floating point math, I would be left with a whole number, no decimal places at all.  We need at least 2.

Comment: This works but I still need to wrap it with a NumberFormat object because of an additional constraint that I forgot to mention.  Basically there is a MAP[Type => NumberFormatter] that this needs to play nicely with.

Comment: Well, I have never used a NumberFormatter...so I don't know the easiest way to wrap it.

Comment: I decided that maybe trying to shoehorn this functionality into the existing class wasn't worth it, so I create a separate method and just used String.format as suggested here.  Thanks!

Comment: This will not be localized. Consider ICU's `CompactDecimalFormat` https://stackoverflow.com/a/55224088/9636

Answer (score 5):

Note that if you have a `BigDecimal`, you can use the `movePointLeft` method:

```
new DecimalFormat("#.00").format(value.movePointLeft(6));
```

Answer (score 5):

For someone looking out there to convert a given digit in human readable form.

```
public static String getHumanReadablePriceFromNumber(long number){

    if(number >= 1000000000){
        return String.format("%.2fB", number/ 1000000000.0);
    }

    if(number >= 1000000){
        return String.format("%.2fM", number/ 1000000.0);
    }

    if(number >= 100000){
        return String.format("%.2fL", number/ 100000.0);
    }

    if(number >=1000){
        return String.format("%.2fK", number/ 1000.0);
    }
    return String.valueOf(number);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a subclass of NumberFormat that I whipped up.  It looks like it does the job but I'm not entirely sure it's the best way:

```
private static final NumberFormat MILLIONS = new NumberFormat()
{
    private NumberFormat LOCAL_REAL = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00M");

    public StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)
    {
        double millions = number / 1000000D;
        if(millions > 0.1) LOCAL_REAL.format(millions, toAppendTo, pos);

        return toAppendTo;
    }

    public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)
    {
        return format((double) number, toAppendTo, pos);
    }

    public Number parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented...");
    }
};
```

Comment: I like the solution from Outlaw, especially as it can also create k/M/G "human readable" formatting without the need for the user of this api to do calculations. He always gets the shortest possible number.


    999999
    999.99k
    999.99M
    999.99G
    999.99T

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply?

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00M");
System.out.println(df.format(n / 1000000));
```

Comment: The division needs to be encapsulated inside the formatter.  Guess I'll update the question to more clearly explain the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin language, you can make extention function:

```
fun Long.formatToShortNumber(): String {
    return when {
        this >= 1000000000 -> String.format("%.2fB", this / 1000000000.0)
        this >= 1000000 -> String.format("%.2fM", this / 1000000.0)
        this >= 1000 -> String.format("%.2fK", this / 1000.0)
        else -> this.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ChoiseFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html).

A more simplistic way would be to use a wrapper that auto divided by 1m for you.

Comment: Took a look a the docs but I'm really not sure how that's going to help me here.  Seems like ChoiceFormat basically contains a bunch of formats and somehow matches the input with one of these sub-formats.  I think I want all input to be handled the same.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you should use ICU's [`CompactDecimalFormat`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CompactDecimalFormat.html), which will localize the formatting result for non-english locales. Other locales might not use a "Millions" suffix.

[This functionality will be standard Java in JDK 12](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8188147) with `CompactNumberFormat`.