# How does the ternary operator work

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I don't understand this code;

Can someone write it proper so I can also understand.

```
public void deleteStudentsPersistence(Student student) {
        em.remove(em.contains(student) ? student : em.merge(student));
    }
```

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it answer your question, or cemment it to ask more details otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator you used there is called a ternary operator and it works almost the same way an if-else statement works. Consider the statement below:

```
int min = (a < b) ? a : b;
```

What this means is: *Evaluate the value of `(a < b)`, if it's true, the value of min is `a`, otherwise, the value of min is `b`*. It can be related to the if-else statement this way: **If (a < b) is true: min = a; else: min is b.**

Back to your question now....

```
em.remove(em.contains(student) ? student : em.merge(student));
```

This means if `em.contains(student)` is true, then perform `em.remove(student)`, however if it's false, then perform `em.remove(em.merge(student))`.

**PS:**

Obviously, in many practical cases that involve giving a variable a value based on a two-way condition, this can be a subtle replacement for if-statement. There is great argument about the "more efficient" method as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745389/is-the-ternary-operator-faster-than-an-if-condition) but I personally prefer to use the ternary operator because of it's relatively short syntax length and readability.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 3):

this is a ternary operator, called conditional operator. it could also be written this way:

```
public void deleteStudentsPersistence(Student student) {
        if (em.contains(student)){
        em.remove(student);
        } else{
        em.remove(em.merge(student));
        }
    }
```

basically, it check if em contains the student before removing, otherwise it merge it