# If statement condition to prevent an empty list?

Tags: java

I'm using a GUI and using lists. When the list is empty and they press the 'show list' button, instead of it just displaying "[]" I want to create an if statement that results in the message "your list is empty" instead. I have tried along the lines of this

```
if(!myList.contains(null)) { // problem here
        listBox.setText(myList.toString());
}else{
        listBox.setText("Your list is empty");
    }
```

I've also tried !myList.contains("") but that doesn't seem to work either. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: null check list, isEmpty() or zero check size()

Comment: Use [`isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty--)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java ArrayList - Check if list is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145235/java-arraylist-check-if-list-is-empty)

Comment: isEmpty worked thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List has an isEmpty method that returns true if there are no items in the list.

```
 if (!myList.isEmpty()) { 
     listBox.setText(myList.toString());
 } else {
     listBox.setText("Your list is empty");
 }
```

Comment: The .isEmpty was what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The isEmpty() function should resolve your problem or maybe you could validate the size with lenght.

It depends on what you want to do, but you should trying to Override the **toString()** method.

[How can I override the toString method of an ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129505/how-can-i-override-the-tostring-method-of-an-arraylist-in-java)

Regards