# Function doesn't update the variable

Tags: java, android

My function is update the ArrayList, but doesn't update the boolean, it's very weird!

I just not understand, or them both updates, or them both not.

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean isEmpty = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addNames(arrayList, isEmpty);
    Log.d("status", arrayList.size() + " " + isEmpty);

}

private void addNames(ArrayList<String> names, boolean empty) {
    names.add("Moshe");
    names.add("Noa");
    names.add("Haim");
    empty = false;
}
```

How can i update the isEmpty variable?
(this.isEmpty = false; is not good for me, i need another way)

Comment: You modified a local variable not the Global one...

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the field to the arg, so empty=false should instead be

```
this.isEmpty = empty
```

As just setting empty = false sets the passed in argument 'empty' to false rather than the field

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong variable. `empty` is the method parameter which has method scope only. The class scope variable is `isEmpty`. You don't need to use `this` in this case.

use `isEmpty = true;`

In your scenario, you don't even need to pass the arguments in that method. Those variables are global and can be accessed without passing them as an argument. Also `isEmpty` is unnecessary when you could use `arrayList.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to any `isEmpty` field, you can check on the fly by calling `arrayList.isEmpty()`.

```
private List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addNames(arrayList);
    Log.d("status", arrayList.size() + " " + arrayList.isEmpty());

}

private void addNames(List<String> names) {
    names.add("Moshe");
    names.add("Noa");
    names.add("Haim");
}
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145235/java-arraylist-check-if-list-is-empty) for further information