# Indian short currency format in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, locale

In google sheets, I am trying to display numbers in Indian 'short' format with lakhs and crore suffix as follows:

- Cell value: 1234, Display as 1.23**K**
- Cell value: 12345, Display as 12.35**K**
- Cell value: 123456, Display as 1.23**L** [L=lakh]
- Cell value: 1234567, Display as 12.35**L**
- Cell value: 12345678, Display as 1.23**C** [C=Crore]
- Cell value: 123456789, Display as 12.35**C**.

I have tried to modify this custom number format:

`[<999950]0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"`

[by Brook McEachern](https://medium.com/@brookinc/the-only-spreadsheet-custom-number-format-you-ll-ever-need-7cc356a7ca3e), but could not able to achieve my required format.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Blog post links to this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573706/how-to-use-unit-abbreviation-in-excel#_=_

Comment: Closest I can get you is this: `[<999950]0.00,"K";[<9999500]0.00,,"L";0.00,,,"C"%%`, but that leaves trailing `%` signs. Sadly, I don't think there's a way to get rid of the percent signs in the output. Unless somebody knows some obscure trick that I don't?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

### indian separator system in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, REPT("(.)", IF(LEN(A2:A)=3, LEN(A2:A)-4, LEN(A2:A)-3))), "0"), 
 "select "&JOIN(",", "Col"&SORT(SEQUENCE(MAX(LEN(A2:A)-3)), 1, )))),,9^9)), " ", ), 
 "(.{2})", "$1,"), REPT("(.)", IF((LEN(A2:A)-3)+ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2)<1, 1, 
 (LEN(A2:A)-3)+ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2)))),
 "select "&JOIN(",", "Col"&SORT(SEQUENCE(MAX((LEN(A2:A)-3)+
 ROUNDDOWN((LEN(A2:A)-3)/2))), 1, )))),,9^9)), " ", ), "^,", )&","&IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "...$"), IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(A2:A, "000"))), "^0,$", ))
```

---

### indian short currency in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(ROUND(A2:A*VLOOKUP(LEN(A2:A), {SEQUENCE(19), 
 {1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 10^-5; 10^-5; 10^-7; 10^-7; 10^-9; 10^-9; 
  10^-11; 10^-11; 10^-13; 10^-13; 10^-15; 10^-15; 10^-17; 10^-17}}, 2, 1), 2)&" "&
 VLOOKUP(LEN(A2:A), {SEQUENCE(19), 
 {"Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "Rp"; "L"; "L"; "Cr"; "Cr"; "Arab"; "Arab"; 
  "Kharab"; "Kharab"; "Nil"; "Nil"; "Padma"; "Padma"; "Shankh"; "Shankh"}}, 2, 1)))
```

- side note: `ROUND` is set to 2 decimal places. this can be set to 0, or `ROUND` can be completely removed, or it can be replaced by `TRUNC` if needed

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jpXvZSDD2kBj1OnGQUIIBVzKcDUB240IGGQpm1bZDv0/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

an alternative approach would be as follows...

#### indian separator system:

```
=INDEX(IF(IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0, REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 REPT(0, 50)&"×"&TEXT(A1:A, "0"), REPT("(..)", 24)&"(...)$", 
 JOIN(",", "$"&SEQUENCE(25))), "(.*×,?)", ), "-,", "-")&
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "(\.\d{1})")), A1:A&""))
```

[image]

---

#### indian short currency:

```
=INDEX(IF((IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0)+(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IFERROR(A1:A*1, 1)=0)), 
 REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TRUNC(IFNA(A1:A*(10^-(
 VLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), 
 SEQUENCE(8, 1, 6, 2), 1)-1)), A1:A), 1), "0.#"), "(\.)$", )&" "&
 HLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), {0, SEQUENCE(1, 8, 4, 2); 
 SPLIT("Rp♦Rp♦L♦Cr♦Arab♦Kharab♦Nil♦Padma♦Shankh", "♦")} , 2), ""&A1:A))
```

[image]

---

#### both indian systems combined:

```
=INDEX(IF((IFERROR(N(ABS(A1:A*1)))>0)+(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IFERROR(A1:A*1, 1)=0)), 
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(
 REPT(0, 50)&"×"&REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TRUNC(IFNA(A1:A*(10^-(
 VLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), 
 SEQUENCE(8, 1, 6, 2), 1)-1)), A1:A), 1), "0"), "(\.)$", ), REPT("(..)", 24)&"(...)$", 
 JOIN(",", "$"&SEQUENCE(25))), "(.*×,?)", ), "-,", "-")&
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"", "(\.\d{1})"))&" "&
 HLOOKUP(LEN(TEXT(INT(ABS(A1:A*1)), "0")), {0, SEQUENCE(1, 8, 4, 2); 
 SPLIT("Rp♦Rp♦L♦Cr♦Arab♦Kharab♦Nil♦Padma♦Shankh", "♦")} , 2), A1:A&""))
```

[image]

---

- works with numeric numbers
- works with plain text numbers
- works with text
- works with empty cells
- works with negative values
- works with zeros
- works with scientific notations
- works with decimals
- works up to Shankh
- works up to 10^±50

---

### [english demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R6EpDjX3_BnySrGl2AIUPYw37LIAEEYbkyp8fCQ_soI/copy)

### [non-english demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vYxwjU_flCZoh7IWDKLfHflEynHc0yhvoY-4Qjsp0S4/copy)