# Suddenly [>9999999]##,##,##,##0;[>99999]##,##,##0;##,##0 stop working in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheet, select a cell having at least 6 digits number in it, then go to Format > Number > Custom number format > (fill the inbox by [>9999999]##,##,##,##0;[>99999]##,##,##0;##,##0 ) and hit Apply.

If the entered number is 195665 then it was showing Indian format lakhs and crores as 1,95,665 but now it shows 195,665. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359814/displaying-lakhs-and-crores-in-google-sheets).

Is there any other number format, which still works in Google sheet ? (It should not be formula like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67261720/indian-short-currency-format-in-google-sheets), but it should be just a number formatting).

Comment: Was this working at some point? Can you try with the following? `[>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0;[>99999]##\,##\,##0;##,##0` https://stackoverflow.com/a/34690816

Comment: Yes it was working nice, but now it is not working. Thank you, the format suggested by you works well.

Comment: However, the format suggested by you works in sheet, when we apply through menu in sheet. But in App script, I run `var trialSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TrialSheet");`
  `trialSheet.getRange("J2").setNumberFormat('[>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0;[>99999]##\,##\,##0;##,##0');`. It doesn't work. When I check, which format is applied to "J2", it was  [>9999999]##,##,##,##0;[>99999]##,##,##0;##,##0.

Comment: If setting via script, try with `.setNumberFormat('[>9999999]##\\,##\\,##\\,##0;[>99999]##\\,##\\,##0;##,##0');`