# Format bigInteger to display unit (example : 1 200 000 => 1.20M )

Tags: android

I would like to know if it was possible ton convert a bigInteger  to unit format (k, M , G , T , P , E ) .
I try to use this topic : [How to go about formatting 1200 to 1.2k in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753251/how-to-go-about-formatting-1200-to-1-2k-in-java) but it only works for long.

Comment: Please share the code you have written so far.