# Java or Android utils to shrink or format large number

Tags: java, android, android-layout, number-formatting

Does android provide a way to shrink or abbreviate large numbers or do I have to roll out my own? For examples

- 1,000 => 1k
- 25,678 => 25.7k
- 3,456,245 => 3.5m

Or at the very least, is there a built-in android/java method for adding commas to numbers?

The reason I would really rather not roll this out myself is because this is for an android app, and I need the app itself to take locale into account.

Comment: Have you seen `NumberFormat`. Here is [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Comment: Take a look at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753251/how-to-go-about-formatting-1200-to-1-2k-in-java).

Comment: Thank you so much. I looked but didn't find it. Sorry for the duplicate question.