# How to go about formatting 1000 Gram to 1 Kg

Tags: java, android

I'd like to format following numbers into the numbers next to them with Android:

I've tried it, by taking the code from [How to go about formatting 1200 to 1.2k in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859525/how-to-go-about-formatting-1200-to-1-2k-in-android-studio)

This works when the value is a multiple of zero, but if there is a number other than zero some are not suitable

```
String numberString = "";
if (Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(weight_total) / 1000) > 1) {
   numberString = (Integer.parseInt(weight_total) / 1000) + " kg";
}
else {
   numberString = weight_total + " gram";
}
tvWeight.setText(": " + numberString);
```

I want to 1000 gram > 1 kg, 1800 gram > 1.8 kg etc

Correct and Wrong weight screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqA0x.jpg

---

Now i am using this code, so its work fine and perfect for my app

```
// Input data
int weightInput = Integer.parseInt(item.getWeight());
String weightOutput;

if (weightInput < 1000) {
    weightOutput = weightInput + " gram";
} else {
    double result = weightInput / 1000.0;
    weightOutput = String.valueOf(result);
    weightOutput = (weightOutput.contains(".0") ? weightOutput.substring(0, weightOutput.length() - 2) : weightOutput) + " kg";
}

System.out.println(weightOutput);
```

Final result https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nxbs.png

Comment: android studio is an IDE, meaning it just helps you to code. please don't use the tag unless you're specifically asking about a feature of the IDE

Comment: If you also need rounding, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` convert `String` into **`int`**.
if you divide an `int` by `int` the result will be `int` too.
use `Float.parseFloat()` instead, or divide it by `1000.0` (make the 1000 non-integer value and then the result will be non-integer too.)
if you want it to be more precise and count milligrams (or even smaller units) you must use `Float.parseFloat()` because the value after the dot will be discarded using `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: yes it worked and helped, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I wrote a java code for this and I am sure it is going to work in android as well.

```
package stackOverflow;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class parseWeight {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   

        //Ignore above


        //assuming you have int as input
        int weightInput = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        String outputString = "";
        if(weightInput < 1000){
            outputString = weightInput + " gram";
        }
        else if(weightInput >= 1000){
            double temp = weightInput / 1000.0;


            //round off upto one decimal places
            double rf = Math.round((temp*10.0)/10.0);
            outputString = rf + " kg";
        }


        tvWeight.setText(": " + outputString);


        //Ignore below
        System.out.println(outputString);

    }
    
}
```

Comment: use double is work fine, thank mate it help