# Converting Numbers Value in Readble Form?

Tags: android

Hi all I am trying to convert followers number into readable string like Instagram. For that I used below code :

```
public static String new_format(double number)
{
    String[] suffix = new String[]{"","K", "M", "B", "T"};
    int MAX_LENGTH = 4;
    String r = new DecimalFormat("##0E0").format(number);
    r = r.replaceAll("E[0-9]", suffix[Character.getNumericValue(r.charAt(r.length() - 1)) / 3]);
    while(r.length() > MAX_LENGTH || r.matches("[0-9]+\\.[a-z]"))
    {
        r = r.substring(0, r.length()-2) + r.substring(r.length() - 1);
    }
    return r;
}
```

But its not giving the right values for example lelepons have 24.2m followers but it is showing 20m. I got this code snipt from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405728/9565955

Answer (score 1):

```
public String formatValue(double value) {
int power; 
    String suffix = " kmbt";
    String formattedNumber = "";

    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#");
    power = (int)StrictMath.log10(value);
    value = value/(Math.pow(10,(power/3)*3));
    formattedNumber=formatter.format(value);
    formattedNumber = formattedNumber + suffix.charAt(power/3);
    return formattedNumber.length()>4 ?  formattedNumber.replaceAll("\\.[0-9]+", "") : formattedNumber;  
}
```

Call this in your OnCreateView to set the return value of this method

`userfollower.setText(formatValue(number));`

Comment: How t can I setText of Text view in the same code ?

Comment: give me your setText name

Comment: `userFollower`.

Comment: @Woods dont forget to mark it as answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Thank You Very Much ! And The first upvote is done by me 

Comment: it worked better then code I found but still it show 24m instead of 24.2m the user is lelepons at Instagram.

Comment: what about the other followers who have millions ?

Comment: @Aliaabhatt shows wrong showing 21m instead of 21.6m

Comment: try new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00M");

Comment: Which methods is this please ebolrate. I used in replacement of `#,###.#` and it's showing very m in every value whether it's 100

Comment: the above simply change this linenew DecimalFormat("#,###.#")  with the one of the comment above

Comment: I changed but as I said it's showing it with wrong figures like this 24Mm

Comment: new DecimalFormat("##0E0"),,,refer here to test more options https://stackoverflow.com/a/20082877/9025311