# Convert cool format to two decimal point

Tags: android, numbers, format

I am using below method to convert number in formatted way like

```
 private static String coolFormat(double n, int iteration) {
    double d = ((long) n / 100) / 10.0;
    boolean isRound = (d * 10) %10 == 0;//true if the decimal part is equal to 0 (then it's trimmed anyway)
    return (d < 1000? //this determines the class, i.e. 'k', 'm' etc
            ((d > 99.9 || isRound || (!isRound && d > 9.99)? //this decides whether to trim the decimals
                    (int) d * 10 / 10 : d + "" // (int) d * 10 / 10 drops the decimal
            ) + "" + c[iteration])
            : coolFormat(d, iteration+1));

}
```

How it can be result for two decimal point.

```
Log.e("PrintValue ", coolFormat(1520,0)+"");

06-01 15:57:07.625 19542-19542/? E/PrintValue: 1.5k
```

If i will enter 1520 OUTPUT=> 1.5k but output should be 1.52k

Comment: From your code it is totally unclear what you want to do. Show some examples of what you have and what you want as result

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  I have updated the question. I need the result in two decimal point. Currently it gives in only single decimal point.

Comment: what is `iteration` for? The code is so messy that it's impossible to understand at least a piece of it.

Comment: Original thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753866/2735471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following method it should work for you

```
public static String formatNumberExample(Number number) {
    char[] suffix = {' ', 'k', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'P', 'E'};
    long numValue = number.longValue();
    int value = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(numValue));
    int base = value / 3;
    if (value >= 3 && base < suffix.length) {
        return new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(numValue / Math.pow(10, base * 3)) + suffix[base];
    } else {
        return new DecimalFormat("#,##0").format(numValue);
    }
}
```

#### Proof:

[image: image_proof]

Comment: @SamosysTechnologies Vote up and accept the answer if it really saved your time.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for vote but from my side it is up voted answer.

Comment: @SamosysTechnologies Thanks.!