# How to actually get abbreviated notation with CompactDecimalFormat?

Tags: android, kotlin

All I want to do is Format numbers in compact (abbreviated) notation, like "1.2K" instead of "1200", but I seem to can't figure out how to do that with [CompactDecimalFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/text/CompactDecimalFormat)

When I do: `CompactDecimalFormat.getInstance().parse("1200")`
it still gives me "1200" and not "1.2K"

Comment: yes possible, The "short" style is also capable of formatting currency amounts, such as "$1.2M" instead of "$1,200,000.00", https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/text/CompactDecimalFormat, https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/text/CompactDecimalFormat.CompactStyle

Comment: CompactDecimalFormat.getInstance(locale: Locale!, style: CompactDecimalFormat.CompactStyle.SHORT).parse("1200"); could work

Comment: @HasanuzzamanRana that doesn't work, [parse is in-op](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/text/CompactDecimalFormat#parse)

This functionality hasn't been ported to [Android yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54110758/2445763). Guess I will take my pick from the gajillion of hacky solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753251/how-to-go-about-formatting-1200-to-1-2k-in-java)

Comment: That should work, as per documentation. then you could follow https://www.iditect.com/how-to/52773332.html

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
val formattedNumber = CompactDecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault(), CompactDecimalFormat.CompactStyle.SHORT).format(12000)
```

Comment: Hi. Please provide some description to your answer. It will help others as well to understand the problem better.

Comment: this works. so it looks like I was suppose to being passing the value into the `format` method and not `parse`.