# JFreechart - want to customize Y axis values

Tags: jfreechart

My Y axis values on a line chart are for example ranging from 645,000 to 667,500.  I would like to be able to add units to the value, such as
645K, to shorten the length of the legend.

I have seen a similar question asked, but the answer given did not provide complete code and was not very helpful.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setNumberFormatOverride()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#setNumberFormatOverride-java.text.NumberFormat-) and pass in a suitable `NumberFormat`, such as the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/529476/230513) for `MILLIONS`.

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new NumberFormat(){…});
```